# sql get row number of record in database(sql server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

database example

```
Id  Name
-----------------    
 0   name0
 1   name1
 2   name2
17   name17
24   name 24
```

I want a SQL statement something like this

```
SELECT waytoFindRowNumber 
FROM example   
WHERE Id = 17
```

So that I get the result as

```
3 ==> the row no. of the matching record
```

How can I get this result?

Thanks

edit

```
Id  Name
-------------------------    
 0  name0  ==> row0
 1  name1 ==> row1
 2  name2 ==> row2
17  name17 ==> row3
24  name 24 ==> row4
```

Comment: question is unclear to me. :(

Comment: name0 is row 0

name1 is row 1

name17 is row 3

Comment: You want it to return 3 rows all of which are the ID 17 row?  You want to return 3 rows starting at ID 17?  Question is unclear

Comment: Since you state that name17 is row3 then the query you posted will return that row. I suspect however that isn't what you want.

Comment: no, i want it to give the number 3

Comment: It will give the number 4 for the given sample data unless you filter it somehow.  Row numbers aren't 0 based.  See my SQL Fiddle on Ouscux's answer.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using ROWNUMBER built-in fucntion;

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
               SELECT *, 
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id, 
                                          ORDER BY Id) rown 
               FROM example 
               WHERE Id=17) tmp
WHERE tmp.rown = 3
```

Comment: it gives no rows back

Comment: This is a little off, you need to move the `ID = 17` outside of the subquery.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/72866/5